# WordPress Custom Walker Menu - Keep custom classes only

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm using WordPress 4.2.1 and I created a custom walker for *wp_nav_menu()*

In the method *start_el()* I get the element classes with the following:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    ...

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : ( array ) $item->classes;

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to get custom class(es) "only"? (Admin/Appearance/Menus -> CSS Classes)

Someone can help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to filter out the wordpress classes...

```
function item_class(Array $item_class)
{

  $cls = array_filter($item_class, function($value) {
     return (str_replace(['menu-', 'page_', 'page-'], '', $value) != $value)  ? false : true;
  });

  return implode(' ', $cls);
}
```

Add to yr walker class, then call with a menu item. eg:

```
 echo '<a class="' . $this->item_class($item->classes) . '">';
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that this appears to still work, as of WordPress 5.2. Wonderful method.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no method to get all custom classes in wordpress. But you can use 2 version of wordpress and origional theme and modifty theme and then compare it using software such as codecompare ,Diff Checker or Win Merge.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your classes into walker class like this .

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'nav-submenu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
}

    function start_el(  &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

    // depth dependent classes
    $depth_classes = array(
        ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-item' : 'nav-submenu-item' ),
        ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
        ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
        'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
    );
    $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

    // passed classes
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

    // build html
    $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

    // link attributes
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

    $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
        $args->before,
        $attributes,
        $args->link_before,
        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
        $args->link_after,
        $args->after
    );

    // build html
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. I need to use custom classes that I set in administration (appearance/menus css classes input) and remove the wp generated classes (menu-item, current_menu_item ...)